# User Video Capture and Storing at Cloud Server using HTML5 with Node.JS or HTML5 with Python or HTML5/JavaScript

Tags: html5-video

Hi  NEED HELP FOR ANIMAL RESCUE TEAM .

We are creating a Video form for to capture multiple videos from Use Mobile [Web app ] of a injured stay dogs and upload in the sever for Vet Doc  inspection for futher guidance .

We are looking for Video  Catpure from End User  from Mobile Web App / Webpage and Storing  at Cloud  Server using  HTML5 with Node.JS or HTML5 with Python or HTML5/JavaScript

Any help or refernce would be usefull !.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks RAKIB Sir,  We have Sample  deployed Webcam Capture App in React JS but we dont not know how to record the video in the server videoformreactv2-s9nqn.ondigitalocean.app  1 > We  need  to create a Video Form for capturing the video of stray animal and store with  e mail ID  and name and phone number of the person with location details  .As NGO ,We cannot afford to pay for IT so we are trying  ourself